# jQuery plugin: Scrollmagic, on complete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollmagic

I'm having trouble figuring out if there's a oncomplete function for ScrollMagic plugin.

What I'm trying to do is, right now, it correctly makes my left fixed div transparent when the user enters the div "Background", but I would like it when the user leaves to have the left div come back, so basically, only animate the left div if it's inside the div "background".

**I think the problem with this is I'm using Maxtween to animate it which sets the opacity to 0 but doesn't change it back.**

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/7zrfLtLk/

```js
$(function(){
            
           var theh= $( ".background" ).height();
            console.log(theh);
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: ".background", duration:theh})
            .setTween("#left", 0.5, {opacity:"0"}) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
            .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"}) // add indicators (requires plugin)*/
            .addTo(controller);
            
            
            });
```

```css
#left{
  position:fixed;
  background:black;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
}
body,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:3000px;
}
.para{
  height:300px;
  widtH:300px;
  background:blue;
  float:right;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.background{
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  float:right;
  margin-top:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>



<div class="para"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

**I found a solution to this in case anyone's looking at this, posted below, not a perfect solution in my opinion but please check it out and let me know your thoughts.**

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is basically triggering the opacity back on the element directly below the div.  See updated fiddle.  Not sure if this is the way to go, feels sort of hackey, I'd rather have a onDestination, bring back to normal.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/7zrfLtLk/1/

```js
$(function(){
        
       var theh= $( ".background" ).height();
        console.log(theh);
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: ".background", duration:theh})
        .setTween("#left", 0.5, {opacity:"0"}) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
        .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"}) // add indicators (requires plugin)*/
        .addTo(controller);
        
       
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: ".background-2"})
        .setTween("#left", 0.5, {opacity:"1"}) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
        .addIndicators({name: "1 (duration: 0)"}) // add indicators (requires plugin)*/
        .addTo(controller);
        
        
        });
```

```css
#left{
  position:fixed;
  background:black;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
}
body,html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:3000px;
}
.para{
  height:300px;
  widtH:300px;
  background:blue;
  float:right;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.background{
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  float:right;
  margin-top:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>



<div class="para"></div>
<div class="background"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```